# alternative for tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention() in tensorflow version 1.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, chatbot, seq2seq

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq' has no attribute 'prepare_attention'

I know that the prepare_attention() has been deprecated. What is the alternative for this? And also please specify the syntax also.

the function I'm using is:
def decoding_layer_train(encoder_state, dec_cell, dec_embed_input, sequence_length, decoding_scope,
                         output_fn, keep_prob, batch_size):
    '''Decode the training data'''

```
attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, dec_cell.output_size])

att_keys, att_vals, att_score_fn, att_construct_fn = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states,
                                             attention_option="bahdanau",
                                             num_units=dec_cell.output_size)

train_decoder_fn = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_train(encoder_state[0],
                                                                 att_keys,
                                                                 att_vals,
                                                                 att_score_fn,
                                                                 att_construct_fn,
                                                                 name = "attn_dec_train")
train_pred, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(dec_cell,
                                                          train_decoder_fn,
                                                          dec_embed_input,
                                                          sequence_length,
                                                          scope=decoding_scope)
train_pred_drop = tf.nn.dropout(train_pred, keep_prob)
return output_fn(train_pred_drop)
```